# вопрос по QTimer

Tags: c++, qt, таймер

здравствуйте, интересует пара вопросов по QTimer т.к. в документации этого нету, я так понял:

1) допустим, есть код:

```
{
    QTimer::singleShot(5000, this, [this](){ std::cout<<"hello world\n"; });
    /*...какие-то долгие вычисления...*/
}
```

когда будет запущен таймер: сразу в строке где вызван singleShot, либо после выхода из scope(т.е. уже после долгих вычислений)?

2) когда 5 секунд прошло после запуска, коллбэк добавляется в очередь обработчиков событий? т.е. если есть 1 уже работающий коллбэк, 2 за ним в очереди, то наш коллбэк от таймера будет 4 уже, или сразу после отработки первого будет вызван, т.е. обгонит 2 последующих?

Comment: Вы хотели сказать 3-й колбек после первых двух? Или подразумевается что-то иное?

Comment: ну вот один выполняется коллбэк уже, очень долго уже, и еще долго будет выполняться, за ним в очереди еще 2 стоят... вот когда срабатывает истекает время таймера, то коллбэк таймера после первого встает в очередь, или после 2 еще?

Comment: После второго. События всегда добавляются в очередь, а значит встают в её конец по мере поступления.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда наступает таймаут таймера, он не вызывает колбэк, он испускает (`emit`) *сигнал*. Сигнал обрабатывается системой метаобъектов Qt, которая берёт список всех подключенных к нему слотов и помещает их в очередь событий (event loop) соответствующего потока. Функция выполнится, как только до неё дойдёт очередь. То есть да, если есть уже работающий слот, то другой будет ждать своей очереди. Но если слоты живут в разных потоках, то они могут выполняться и одновременно. Очерёдность определяется планировщиком задач операционной системы.

А таймер будет запущен сразу после вызова `singleShot`.

Comment: а еще такой вопрос: я так понимаю, таймер запускается как-то "параллельно", а как конкретно? в другом потоке, или это аппаратное что-то?

Comment: @xperious, таймеры предоставляются операционной системой. `QTimer` - просто удобная обёртка.